# growth over last year

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to take out the growth of every row in new column, I have no idea how to do it and is there any way to remove the digits from Bricks column?

thanks[image]

Comment: `df['Brick']=df['Brick'].str.split(' ',1).str[1]`

Comment: for some reason 'Brick' doesn't appear in my columns?

Comment: check df.columns if Brick was not present then check df.index

Comment: thanks i got it , do you know how to calculate the growth in new column?

Comment: do you mean to store that number in Bricks in new column called growth?

Comment: yes, comparing year 2020 with 21.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233094/discussion-between-sajjad-ali-and-anurag-dabas).